# Python xor binary data with decimal value

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitwise-xor

I'm a little bit confused about the behavior of the bitwise xor operator. Why, if xor is possible only with binary data, am I able to use xor with decimal numbers?

For example:

```
fs='a'
sn='k'    
ord(fs) ^ ord(sn)
```

`ord(fs)` gives me an ASCII code that is not binary.

Comment: Why do you think a ascii code isn't binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Python 3 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) for built-in functions, `ord()` returns an integer:

> Given a string representing one Unicode character, return an integer representing the Unicode code point of that character. For example, ord('a') returns the integer 97 [...]

This integer is represented by a sequence of bits, and so it is a valid operand to the bitwise XOR operator.

**Edit**

Python interprets the value `97` as an integer. And, internally, the integer numeric type is represented as a sequence of bits. The integer type is described in [Numeric Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric). Another section of that same documentation explains [Bitwise Operations on Integer Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types), and it states that

> Bitwise operations only make sense for integers.

That is, bitwise operations on any other type, including a string, are invalid in Python.

So `ord()` returns an integer. Which is represented *internally* as a sequence of bits. Although its type is not explicitly "binary," Python still defines the bitwise XOR operator for integers.

To be clear, all values are represented internally as a sequence of bits. It's just that Python only defines the bitwise XOR operator for integers.

Comment: Still a little confused, string is a sequence of bit, but in python if I type 97 is integer not bit right?

Answer (score 0):

It works exactly as designed, just that you need to assign it to a variable, and print them.

You can convert them (=integers) back to a binary strings like this `'{0:b}'.format(some_integer)`. The `.zfill(8)` in the below example is to "*zero fill left to 8 chars*" to align them up neatly.

Example:

```
fs='a' 
sn='k'

#assign result to variable
r = ord(fs) ^ ord(sn)

print('fs=', str(ord(fs)).rjust(3), '{0:b}'.format(ord(fs)).zfill(8))
print('sn=', str(ord(sn)).rjust(3), '{0:b}'.format(ord(sn)).zfill(8))
print('r =', str(r).rjust(3), '{0:b}'.format(r).zfill(8))
```

output:

```
fs=  97 01100001
sn= 107 01101011
r =  10 00001010
```